# .focus() not working in firefox esr but is in Chome and FF quantum

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus

Is there any reason why this code would work in Chrome/FF but not in Firefox ESR?

```
console.log('before');
var element = window.document.querySelector('.someClass');
if (msg.data.result === 'save') {
  element.setAttribute('save', 'true');
}
element.focus();
element.classList.remove('someClass');
console.log('after');
```

I do see the 2 `console.log` statements being executed but focus is never set.

Comment: give HTML please)))and full js